# Pattern with recursions (C++)

Tags: c++, recursion, variable-assignment

I suspect that This pattern has something to do with the fibonacci, but I have a hard time linking this.

I have to use only recursions.

I've think that code is somewhat like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int pattern(int number)
{
    if(number % 3 == 1)
    {
        cout << "--|^++" << endl;
        return number - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return pattern(number - 1);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int number,newNumber;
    cout << "Please give the number to print" << endl;
    cin >> number;
    newNumber = number * 2;
    pattern(newNumber);

    getch();
}
```

What I can notice in this pattern that in every odd number there is a
"--|^++".

With 2 and 6 there is a << "-||^++" << endl;

Number is 5

```
--|^++
-||^+++
--|^++
|||^^+++++
--|^++
-||^+++
|||||^^^++++++++
```

This has already took my afternoon, I need advice or a book.

I need the solution to this pattern or a code, the difference between " % " and "/" , and error checking.

Comment: The code you posted shouldn't recurse *at all* thanks to `else if(condition == 2,6)`, which will always be `true` due to the comma operator throwing away the left side and returning the right side.

Comment: Sorry, I am not that good as a programmer. That's why I type in random thing inside it. So, it should be only be if and else statement right?

Comment: If you want to print `"-||^+++"` for `2` or `6`, you'll need to test against both: `if(condition == 2 || condition == 6)`.

Comment: Xeo, I tried that. But, it won't appear in the ouput.

Comment: Anyway, what is the actual question here?

Comment: @JuanDelCarlos: Regarding your last comment, you should learn the absolute basics first. You don't learn effectively if you do not know what you do.

Comment: @Gorpik, how can I do this pattern? With only recursions.

Comment: @phresnel, I am just confused with the pattern given to me. My brain is numb from all the thing that I tried to notice in the pattern. One is that 6 * 2 = 12 , 6 and 2 will appear "-||^+++" and odd numbers will give out "--|^++", lastly... 4,8 and 12. Has this kind of increasing prints in it.

Comment: what is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Rohit, the solution for this pattern. I already figured out the the other pattern. All i need is the 4, 8, 12 thing. That increases the "| " , " + " and " ^ "

Comment: @JuanDelCarlos: I am quite sure that this has nothing to do with pattern matching, so don't re-add the tag.

Comment: add them as cases in the function's else if loop

Comment: @Rohit, I am not allowed to use any other than recursions.

Comment: `if(condition % 1)`. This is always true.

Comment: I am now trying to get that the remain if it is 1, then it should print "--|^++"

Comment: If you have already figured out the pattern, show it in the question. If you have problems with c++, then use pseudo code. The question as it stands does not make sense, so I am voting to close. Think of what you want to ask (how are the patterns related to Fibonacci if you know), and come up with a concrete question other than do my homework for me (and tag as homework if it is in fact an assignment)

Comment: You say that you can only use recursion. Operators, conditionals, loops, input, and output aren't recursive, does that mean you aren't allowed to use them? It would be better to tell us exactly what has been disallowed by your instructor. Also, we can't deduce the pattern for the output if you only give one example. You show us the results for `pattern(5)`, and that's great! now show us the output of `pattern(0)` through `pattern(4)`. Or even better, could you copy and paste the problem description your instructor gave you?

Answer (score 1):

The else-branch will never be taken as your second if-condition is always true:

```
else if(condition == 2,6)
```

The comma is the sequence operator which will run all sub-expressions left-to-right, and the value of it is the right-most sub-expression.

Effectively, the line is roughly equivalent to

```
condition == 2;
if (6)
```

An if-condition is considered true if the value is not zero, therefore, it is always true here.

If your intention was to test whether `condition` is 2 or 6, you must be explicit:

```
else if (condition == 2 || condition == 6)
```

Comment: What I saw from Xeo is else if(condition == 2 || 6) 

I suspect that there is some kind of divison that the remainder should be always 0. To it to appear.

Comment: I can't tell exactly what you want to achive from what you posted so far, but note that `if (condition == 2 || 6)` is again probably not what you want. As said, you should learn the basics first. Confusion like this is highly counter-productive to your learning success.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I don't understand your question . But there are a few problems with your 'pattern' function

1. `else if(condition == 2,6)` - will always be true; as explained above
2. `if(condition % 1)`- will always be false ; since any integer is always divisible by one,     this is equal to if(0)
3. the function doesn't return on all code paths ; your else if block should have a return         statement